# Selenium, JS - Impossible to pass a getText() result to the variable

Tags: javascript, selenium, async-await

Writing some tests using Selenium + Chrome.

Have an array named `dates` that contains two elements, empty array `allDates` and code like this:

```
    dates.forEach(async date => {
      console.log(" ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 42 ~ position", await date.getText());
      let newDate = await date.getText();
      console.log(" ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 44 ~ newDate", newDate)
      allDates.push(newDate);
    })
    console.log(" ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 47 ~ allDates", allDates)
```

but the output looks like so:

```
 ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 47 ~ allDates []
    ✓ First test (678ms)
 ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 42 ~ position 26-02-2021
 ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 42 ~ position 06.11.2020
```

First of all it's strange that first is the last console.log (even before the test name). But the biggest problem for me is that it completely omit second console.log (this with `line 44` in the middle).

I tried to write data to `newDate` variable in a few ways like:

```
let newDate = (await date.getText()).toString();

let newDate = await date.getAttribute('value');

let newDate = (await date.getAttribute('value')).toString();
```

but none of the above did work.

So few questions:

1. **How can I modify it to be able to store newDate variable in an array?**
2. Why console.log with `line 44` is not displayed even with an empty value?
3. Why console.logs and test name are not in the correct order?

Comment: which framework are you using

Comment: did you tried alldates = await dates.getText()4

Comment: Store the promise in the array and then use `Promise.all(allDates);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for-loop` instead of `forEach`

```
for (const date of dates) {
  console.log(" ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 42 ~ position", await date.getText());
  let newDate = await date.getText();
  console.log(" ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 44 ~ newDate", newDate)
  allDates.push(newDate);
}

console.log(" ~ file: runSelenium.js ~ line 47 ~ allDates", allDates)
```